# Report Viewer looks bad with master page?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I am using report viewer control with my web application, if I use it without master page it looks perfect but if i use it inside masterpage, it has lots of formatting and css issues. does anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

Because it may some Css files affect the appearance of your `reportviewer container` ,so try to remove the CSS files one by one from your master page and check the look every time so that u know the exact file which cause your problem,after that you can make a custom style to your report viewer container .